# Issue about mixing font labels text and maths equations with \bm option

Tags: pdftex, bold, boldmath, matplotlib

I try to generate a pdf from this source in python (`matplotlib`), in order to have a Latex style :

```
mpl.use("pgf")
rc_fonts = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    'text.latex.preview': True, # Gives correct legend alignment.
    'mathtext.default': 'regular',
    'text.latex.preamble': [r"""\usepackage{bm}"""],
}
mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)
plt.clf()

plt.title(r'\textbf{FoM - GCsp + XC vs} $\bm{1/\sigma}$ \textbf{for} $\bm{\alpha = b_{sp}/b_{ph}}$', fontsize=10)
```

But I get errors like this :

```
ValueError: Error processing '\textbf{FoM - GCsp + XC vs} \(\displaystyle \bm{1/\sigma}\) \textbf{for} \(\displaystyle \bm{\alpha = b_{sp}/b_{ph}}\)'
LaTeX Output:

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/DejaVuSans.ttf(0)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/DejaVuSans.ttf(0)/m/n' instead on input line 0.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...- GCsp + XC vs} \(\displaystyle \bm
                                                  {1/\sigma }\) \textbf {for...
<*> ...displaystyle \bm{\alpha = b_{sp}/b_{ph}}\)}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

I can't understand where these errors come from, if someone could see what's wrong, this would be fine to indicate it.

PS: by the way, is there a way to produce directly a Latex PDF figure from matplotlib with all labels axes and title (including text and maths symbols) in bold ?

Comment: the error is that `\bm` is not defined, presumably you have not loaded the bm package

Comment: also where does `\(\displaystyle ` come from, your source just has `$\bm{1/\sigma}$` `\displaystyle` in inline math is usually wrong.

Comment: looking at your font encodings TU... it appears you are using luatex or xetex, bm mostly does not work with unicode math fonts.  To get all text bold do not use \bm at all simply use `\bfseries \boldmath` where the first makes text bold and the second makes math bold